# Some IDEs automatically use DIVs

Tags: html, xhtml, ide, aptana

I use Aptana Studio 1.5 for PHP development. I want an IDE through which I can just drag-n-drop HTML controls on the Form. I also want the IDE to use DIVs always. At present I manually code using TABLE.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIVs are something you really should learn to code by hand. Most IDEs are not very good at automatically generating the CSS necessary for using DIVs.

It sounds like you want the equivalent of Visual Studio for PHP, and while there are many great editors out there, Aptana being high on the list, most don't have the same kind of visual design tools as Visual Studio. That has a lot to do with the fact that Visual Studio produces ASP web forms with its Visual tools which are hooked into by the .NET code and formatted into HTML by the ASP server.  PHP does not work with an ASP web form type of infrastructure in and of itself.